# Phonegap project organization / build tools

Tags: cordova, build-process, gruntjs

I've been kicking the tires on Phonegap and I'm getting started with my
first real project.

One thing I haven't seen a solution for in the tutorials I've come
across is project organization. Let's say I'm targeting Android and iOS.

I'll have one folder for the iOS stuff and I'll have one folder for the
Android stuff. Both of these folders will have a www folder a couple of
levels down and that's where all my code actually lives since the rest
is just boilerplate for the different platforms.

Now how do I go about managing this without resorting to code
duplication? The simplest strategy might be to just have the www folder
live somewhere else and symlink to it from within both the iOS and
Android code trees.

One step up from that would be to use some kind of
build tool that runs before the iOS/Android compilers. This would facilitate
stuff like build with unminified vs minified code and a lot of other
options.

If I am to use a build tool, what are good/popular options? [gruntjs](http://gruntjs.com)
seems to be gaining popularity with js-heavy projects. Is it a good fit for Phonegap?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree that there are very little documentation on the subject.  This is also because they are still working on it for PhoneGap 3.  They redid the entire project structure for PhoneGap 3 to create a standard way for organizing things.  See this article:  http://blog.safaribooksonline.com/2013/07/19/streamline-cross-platform-development-using-apache-cordova-phonegap-cli/

[Summary] Basically you have folders like:

/merges - for merging/overriding www folder

/platforms - contain native codes

/plugins - plugin codes

/www - primary folder web app folder

They have not gotten around to write any documentation because all of this is automatically created for you with nodejs and their cli tools.  This project structure also help create consistency with their PG online build tools.

Personally, we do not use the online build tool.  This is because we have some massive customization in our code and write our own native plugins.  We also use node, gruntjs, and Jenkins (on osx) in our internal continuous integration build.  This allow us to produce cross platform builds.  We are not on PG 3 yet, but we use the same folder structure so hopefully it'll be a smooth upgrade.

Comment: I hope you see this response/comment. I'm very interested in you guys do your phonegap builds without going through the online build.phonegap.com site. Keeping my fingers crossed that you see this in a timely manner...

Comment: ganders I believe he's using the CLI

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Noogen, both on the basic structure of a Phonegap 3.0 project and on the observation that good documentation is lacking.

My observation is that when you "run" or "build" the app on Android via the command-line interface, the /www folder is indeed the source used for the APK's www folder (as well as AndroidManifest.xml being based on /www/config.xml).

Whereas for iOS, oivvio seems to be right that the www resources are taken from the /platforms/ios/www folder, so if you are working and testing on both Android and iOS simultaneously, you'll need to keep working on the main /www folder resources and keep copying (overwriting) them over to the /platforms/ios/www folder.

No mention of this in the docs, of course.

Answer (score 1):

Readers may be interested in build-sencha-deploy-phonegapbuild.sh a CLI (pure bash) tool to automate CI and building with Sencha (optional) and PhoneGap Build:

https://github.com/mobimentum/build-sencha-deploy-phonegapbuild